# Why is : $ [ \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n ]^{ A_n } : \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n ]^{ S_n } ] = [ \mathfrak{S}_n : \mathfrak{A}_n ] $?

Tags: polynomials, finite-groups, field-theory, galois-theory

How to show that : 
$$ [ \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n ]^{ \mathfrak{A}_n } : \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n ]^{ \mathfrak{S}_n } ]= [ \mathfrak{S}_n : \mathfrak{A}_n ] $$
 such that :

$ \mathfrak{S}_n $ : the symmetric group

$ \mathfrak{A}_n $ : the alternating subgroup of $ \mathfrak{S}_n $.

$ \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n ]^{ \mathfrak{S}_n } $ : the space of invariants polynomials under the action of : $ \mathfrak{S}_n $

$ \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n ]^{ \mathfrak{A}_n } $ : the space of invariants polynomials under the action of : $ \mathfrak{A}_n $

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can do this very explicitly. The $S_n$-invariants are the polynomial ring on the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1, \dots e_n$. The $A_n$-invariants are generated as an algebra over the $S_n$-invariants by the discriminant $\prod_{i < j} (x_i - x_j)$, which is not a symmetric polynomial but which squares to one (although I don't know how hard it is to check that this is all you need). Abstractly I think it ought to follow from some Galois theory applied to the corresponding fields of fractions but there might be some details to check.

Comment: Thank you, but can you give me an answer using Galois theory ? It's seems that : $ F \ : \ G \to \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n ]^G $ is contravariant, so i say, we can use Galois correspondance to prove it, but i don't know how.  :)

Comment: Well, always, if $\Gamma$ is a finite group acting as automorphisms of a field $K$, you have $[K:K^\Gamma]=|\Gamma|$. That’s Galois-theory, and all follows from that.

Comment: @Lubin : Thank you. Where may i find this result you use related to Galois theory please ? I don't find such a property in all Galois theory books i visit. :-)

Comment: Well, I consider this Theorem Zero of Galois Theory. It’s due to Artin, and it may be found as Theorem 1.8 of Chapter VI in Lang’s *Algebra*, Revised Third Edition (2002), p. 264.

Comment: But, $ \mathbb{R} [x_1 , \dots , x_n] $ is not a field, so we cannot use : $ [K \ : \ K^{ \Gamma} ] = | \Gamma | $, right ?